# Am I using the correct custom security service?

Tags: firewall, port

I have a documentation system that needs to send user updates regularily to users that do not sit on the same network. The network that the documentation system resides is up until now a closed one. I have to allow only mail sent from the network. I have a Netgear Prosafe firewall FVS318. I have simply created a custom rule that blocks all outgoing ports except for port 25 and now 53. is this sufficient?

The ports are now changed as shown in the pictures below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrncn.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBJne.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct (i.e. canonical) way to set this up is:

- change the default action to "block"
- Create a rule to allow traffic from port (internal) TCP 0:65535 to (any) TCP 25

That, however, will not be enough for mail to flow through: you also need some sort of DNS resolution. If that isn't already provided (for instance, by using the firewall as DNS server), you also will need to allow UDP and TCP connections to port 53

Comment: +1 but canonical <> correct.

Comment: @Stephane, I wanted to do this but I do not have the option to delete or edit the default value. Or better said I dont know how to access that option

Comment: @John I wanted to express the fact that this is not the only way to make it work but that is the recommended way. Sorry if that isn't the usual way to express that in english

Comment: @DavidDrennan There must be a way to change that because otherwise that firewall would be pretty useless. I suspect it is confîgured elsewhere. You mentioned that the network was "a closed one", perhapse if you explained what you mean by that it would make things clearer

Comment: @Stephanie, with regard to the closed network I only meant that it was never intended to have outside access other than for communication between the few machines on the network(dvs no Internet access). Now that network will be connected to the internet through the firewall. I will look to see where I can disable the default setting. I have changed the settings now to allow port 53 to be open and will add the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it all looks good.

Enable logging initially to see what is going on.

Understanding your routing table on a system level would give you more insight. Your headed in the right direction :)